# Coverage by Jest tests of a React component to call a function when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have a functional React component that renders a button that, when clicked, calls a handleSave function from the props with a passed argument. I try to cover the component with tests, but I can't win, the test crashes in the console with an error that the function was not called. Attached the component and test code:

```
// component
function Modal(props) {
  const { handleSave } = props;

  return (
    <button onClick={() => {handleSave('someInfo')}}>Save</button>
  )
}

// test
describe('ModalComponent', () => {
  it('should call handleSave function', () => {
    const onSaveClickMock = jest.fn();

    const component = mount(<Modal handleSave={onSaveClickMock} />);
    const button = component.find('button');
    button.simulate('click');
    expect(onSaveClickMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
  })
})
```

As I understand it, this test implementation would work if the handleSave function was directly passed to onClick like this:

```
<button onClick={handleSave}>Save</button>
```

How can I implement a test when the function is not just passed to the onClick attribute, but called with the passed argument?

Comment: You test it exactly the same. All that matters from the test's perspective is that `handleSave` is invoked at the right time with the right parameters; it doesn't matter whether that's by `onClick={callback}` or `onClick={event => callback(event)}`, for example. If that test doesn't pass, perhaps there's some other button being clicked on - does the test fail for this specific [mre]?

Comment: Yes, but in this case, another method (toHaveBeenCalledWith()) really helped. But thanks anyway

Comment: You said .toHaveBeenCalled failed because the function wasn't called, at all, so how can testing it was called _with particular arguments_ pass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there's [a helper method](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tohavebeencalledwitharg1-arg2-) for that: `toHaveBeenCalledWith()` (alias - `toBeCalledWith()`):

> Use .toHaveBeenCalledWith to ensure that a mock function was called
> with specific arguments.

So your test might look like this:

```
it('should call handleSave function with a predefined value', () => {
  const onSaveClickMock = jest.fn();
  const predefinedValue = 'someInfo';

  const component = mount(<Modal handleSave={onSaveClickMock} />);
  const button = component.find('button');
  button.simulate('click');
  expect(onSaveClickMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith(predefinedValue);
});
```

Note that if you're indeed sending a predefined value to that function, you should seriously consider abstracting it as a constant (and importing this constant in your test). This way you won't have to update this value twice when needed.

Comment: @Max did it? Because that's the same error you reported in _this_ question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, it helped me, but I described in more detail in a previous comment.

Comment: @Max it's bad form to hassle people who answered your previous questions every time you have a new one, there are plenty of other users on SO. And it's still not clear how this helped you at all, given your new question has _exactly the same problem_ which this answer does not solve. Also you've still oversimplified the component too much because, as I commented there, the test passes.

Comment: @jonrsharpe While the OP indeed mixes up two things, for some reason I always thought it's key part is not an error, but a question about checking the callee's arguments.